# Incomplete Gamma function in scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to compute what wolfram alpha calls the incomplete gamma function [(see here)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%5B0,%200.1%5D):

```
`gamma[0, 0.1]`
```

The wolfram alpha output is `1.822`. The only thing `scipy` gives me that resembles this is `scipy.special.gammainc`, but it has a different [definition](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammainc.html#scipy.special.gammainc) than how wolfram alpha defines their incomplete gamma function.

Not surprisingly

```
import scipy
scipy.special.gammainc(0, 0.1)
```

gives me `nan`. Does `scipy` support what I'm looking for?

Comment: Sympy's version of (upper) incomplete gamma `sympy.functions.special.gamma_functions.uppergamma` has the same definition as mathematica.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately scipys gammaincc does not support a value of `a=0`. But you could define your own `inc_gamma`:

```
from scipy.special import gamma, gammaincc, exp1
def inc_gamma(a, x):
    return exp1(x) if a == 0 else gamma(a)*gammaincc(a, x)
```

Then `inc_gamma(0, 0.1)` will give you `1.8229239584193906`.

Answer (score 10):

According to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammainc.html, the first argument must be positive, whereas you have zero; that's why you're getting NaN.

That said, suppose we try to compute `Gamma[0.01,0.1]` instead. In this case WolframAlpha returns `1.80324`:

[image]

According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html, this is the Upper Incomplete Gamma Function, whereas what Scipy outputs is a scaled version of what WolframAlpha calls the Lower Incomplete Gamma Function. By using the identity in Equation 10, one can see that in cases where a>0, you can use the following:

```
from scipy.special import gammainc
from scipy.special import gamma
gamma(0.01)*(1 - gammainc(0.01,0.1))
```

which returns `1.8032413569025461` in agreement with WolframAlpha.

In short, `Gamma[a,x]` in WolframAlpha corresponds to `gamma(a)*(1-gammainc(a,x))` in Scipy, provided that `a>0`.

Comment: Instead of `1 - gammainc(0.01, 0.1)`, you can use `gammaincc(0.01, 0.1)`.