# Log of exp1 in scipy

Tags: python, scipy

The following

```
from scipy.special import gamma

gamma(x)
```

overflows for large `x`. This is why scipy provides `gammaln`, which is equivalent to `np.log(gamma(x))` and allows us to work in log space and avoid overflow.

Is there anything like this for scipy's [`exp1`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.exp1.html) function? I'd like to have something that returns the same as below but without underflowing for large `x`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import exp1

def exp1ln(x):
    return np.log(exp1(x))
```

(My reasoning for thinking this would be similar to `gammaln` is because `exp1` is in the same family of functions, see here: [Incomplete Gamma function in scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713199/incomplete-gamma-function-in-scipy) .)

Thanks

Comment: For complex `x` or only real `x`?

Comment: @orlp Thanks forgot to specify, real `x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For real *x* you can use the series expansion of log(Ei(*x*)) for *x* → ∞ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Asymptotic_(divergent)_series)) which is highly accurate for large `x`.

From some quick experimentation, 18 terms is enough for full float precision when x >= 50 (and
that's around where `scipy` starts losing full precision). Also the series expansion is really nice,
the coefficients being the factorial numbers, so we can use precise evaluation without catastrophic
cancellation:

```
def _exp1ln_taylor(x, k):
    r = 0; s = -1
    for i in range(k, 0, -1):
        r = (r + s) * i / x
        s = -s
    return r*s

def exp1ln(x):
    x = np.array(x)
    use_approx = x >= 50

    # Avoid infinity/underflows from outside domain.
    ax = np.where(use_approx, x, 100)
    sx = np.where(use_approx, 1, x)
    approx = -x + -np.log(x) + np.log1p(_exp1ln_taylor(ax, 18))
    sp = np.log(scipy.special.exp1(sx))
    return np.where(use_approx, approx, sp) * 1
```

Comparison to WolframAlpha (which can provide hundreds of digits):

```
x           exp1ln(x)           WolframAlpha
0.1         0.6004417824948862  0.6004417824948862
1          -1.5169319590020440 -1.5169319590020456
10         -12.390724371937408 -12.390724371937408
100        -104.61502435050535 -104.61502435050535
1000       -1006.9087537832978 -1006.9087537832978
1000000000 -1000000020.7232659 -1000000020.7232658
```

Comment: This is beautiful, thanks! I'd tried the convergent series expansion and then gave up when it wasn't even close after a few terms (like it says in the article you linked), never even saw the divergent one

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants a version of `exp1ln` that deals only with single numbers instead of arrays, I adapted the solution from [orlp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565635/orlp) to get this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import exp1

def _exp1ln_taylor(x, k):
    r = 0
    s = -1
    for i in range(k, 0, -1):
        r = (r + s) * i / x
        s *= -1
    return r * s

def exp1ln(x):
    if x <= 50:
        return np.log(exp1(x))
    else:
        return -x - np.log(x) + np.log1p(_exp1ln_taylor(x, 18))
```